# Vector that has same direction $2\vec{a}-3\vec{b}$.

Tags: vectors

let $\vec{a}=\langle-3,4\rangle$ and $\vec{b}=\langle 1,2\rangle$. find a vector with length $3$ and having the same direction as $2\vec{a}-3\vec{b}$.

the only thing I have done is finding $2\vec{a}-3\vec{b}$.
what should I do next?

Comment: What is the length of $2a-3b$? Can you scale this vector to have length 3?

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
2 \mathbf{a} - 3 \mathbf{b} = 2 \langle -3,4\rangle - 3 \langle 1,2 \rangle = \langle -9 ,2\rangle, \qquad
\|2 \mathbf{a} - 3 \mathbf{b} \| = \smash{\sqrt{(-9)^2+2^2}} = \sqrt{85}.
$$
Therefore, a *unit* vector (length $1$) in the direction of $2 \mathbf{a} - 3 \mathbf{b}$ would be
$$
\biggl( \dfrac{1}{\| 2 \mathbf{a} - 3 \mathbf{b}\|} \biggr) (2 \mathbf{a} - 3 \mathbf{b}) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{85}} \langle -9,2 \rangle,
$$
and so a vector of length $3$ in the direction of $2 \mathbf{a} - 3 \mathbf{b}$ would be $3$ times that unit vector:
$$
\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{85}} \langle -9,2 \rangle.
$$

---

In general, if you have a vector $\mathbf{v}$, and if you want a vector that is in the same direction as $\mathbf{v}$ and has length $k$ (so $k > 0$), begin by finding the unit vector $(1 / \| \mathbf{v} \|)\mathbf{v}$, which has the same direction as $\mathbf{v}$. Then the vector $$\biggl( \dfrac{k}{\| \mathbf{v} \|} \biggr) \mathbf{v} $$ is the one we want: since it is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{v}$, where the scalar $k/\| \mathbf{v}\|$ is positive, it has the same direction as $\mathbf{v}$, and since 
$$
\biggl\| \biggl(\dfrac{k}{\|\mathbf{v}\|} \biggr) \mathbf{v} \biggr\| = \biggl| \dfrac{k}{\| \mathbf{v} \|} \biggr| \cdot \| \mathbf{v} \| = \dfrac{k}{\|\mathbf{v} \|} \cdot \| \mathbf{v} \| = k,
$$
it has length $k$.